# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.open_model_zoo' when I tried to "pot -h"

Tags: openvino

Currently the pot 1.0 (post training optimization) has been installed already. And I can see pot 1.0 in the result list of command `pip list`. But when I tried to test `pot -h`, I got an error message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.open_model_zoo'

And then I checked the list with `pip list`, there is not "libs" in it. when the libs package should be installed, and how to install it? BTW, i ran model optimizer and inference engine in my laptop successfully.

here is the variable value of system variable "PYTHONPATH":

```
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\python\python3.7;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\model_optimizer;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo;
```

Here is the variable value of system variable "OPENVINOPATH":

```
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Release;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Debug;
%HDDL_INSTALL_DIR%\bin;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\opencv\bin;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\openvx\bin;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\ngraph\lib;
%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\external\tbb\bin;
```

and the %OPENVINO_PATH% is added in the PATH variable.

Here is the error message I got:

```
(3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pot -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\utils\ac_imports.py", line 15, in <module>
from libs.open_model_zoo.tools.accuracy_checker.\
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.open_model_zoo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\Scripts\pot-script.py", line 30, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('pot==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pot')())
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\Scripts\pot-script.py", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
return next(matches).load()
File "C:\Users\310091560\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 178, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\app\run.py", line 20, in <module>
from compression.configs.config import Config
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .algorithms.quantization.accuracy_aware.algorithm import AccuracyAwareQuantization
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\algorithms\quantization\accuracy_aware\algorithm.py", line 20, in <module>
from .utils import create_metric_config, is_preset_performance, \
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\algorithms\quantization\accuracy_aware\utils.py", line 20, in <module>
from ....algorithms.quantization import utils as eu
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\algorithms\quantization\utils.py", line 19, in <module>
from ...engines.ac_engine import ACEngine
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\engines\ac_engine.py", line 22, in <module>
from ..data_loaders.ac_data_loader import ACDataLoader
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\data_loaders\ac_data_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
from ..utils.ac_imports import Dataset, DatasetWrapper
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\pot-1.0-py3.7.egg\compression\utils\ac_imports.py", line 24, in <module>
from accuracy_checker.evaluators.quantization_model_evaluator import create_model_evaluator
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\accuracy_checker-0.8.7-py3.7.egg\accuracy_checker\evaluators\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from .model_evaluator import ModelEvaluator
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\accuracy_checker-0.8.7-py3.7.egg\accuracy_checker\evaluators\model_evaluator.py", line 21, in <module>
from ..utils import get_path, extract_image_representations, is_path
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\accuracy_checker-0.8.7-py3.7.egg\accuracy_checker\utils.py", line 41, in <module>
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 19, in <module>
from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in <module>
from shapely.geos import lgeos
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 154, in <module>
_lgeos = CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Library', 'bin', 'geos_c.dll'))
File "C:\Users\310091560\Miniconda3\envs\3D-Medical-Segmentation-GAN\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the OpenVINO™ toolkit package, the 'libs.open_model_zoo' should be included in the installation package.
However, if you are using open source OpenVINO, you can try to run the following command to check the installation:

git clone https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo.git

cmake -E copy_directory ./open_model_zoo/ /deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/

Then, install the POT by referring to [Installation POT from PyPI](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/pot_InstallationGuide.html#installation_pot_from_pypi)

Comment: Thanks your answer. I was using the OpenVINO toolkit package. And i have run model optimizer and inference engine in my laptop successfully under the current environment. So does it mean that model optimizer and inference engine donot depend on the "libs.open_model_zoo"? How to make it include "libs.open_model_zoo" now? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Model Optimizer is a tool to import, convert, and optimize models that were trained in popular frameworks to a format usable by Intel tools, especially the Inference Engine. Inference Engine is the engine that runs the deep learning model. It includes a set of libraries for an easy inference integration into your applications. Thus, model optimizer and inference engine does not depends on "libs.open_model_zoo". Seems like something is wrong with your installation.
You may reinstall the OpenVINO 2021.4. Then, try to re-install and set up POT by referring to the following link:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/pot_InstallationGuide.html#install_and_set_up_pot_from_intel_distribution_of_openvino_toolkit_package